# How to test for no input in Python 3.3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I'm working on a Python program that returns the word that occurs most times in however many lines of input, with the last line being the string "###".

```
poetry  = []
max = 0
maxitem = None
while True:
 poetry.append(input().lower().split())
for x in poetry:
    count =  poetry.count(x)
if count > max:
    max = count
    maxitem = x
    print(maxitem)
```

Now, the main problem I have is the EOF error I get in the body of the while loop.  As far as I can tell, the reason behind this is that it continually calls for a new line of input, but it gets none.  I do not know how to rectify this.  Any help with the rest of the program would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You could `try` your code and catch the SyntaxError, making your code process an empty string or just continue iterating.

Comment: @Dolphiniac: What `SyntaxError`? Did you try running this python-3.x code in 2.x?

Comment: @abarnert Perhaps I did.  Thanks.  I guess I need to update.

Comment: @Dolphiniac: not really, most people are still using 2.x. However, if you want to run 3.x code, install Python 3 alongside 2.

Comment: … or use an online Python 3 interpreter, or just don't answer questions tagged python-3.x. But yeah, I'd suggest having a 3.3.x alongside your 2.x, and putting some time into learning it. The only downside is that once you use `yield from`, or get exceptions with chained causes while debugging, it's hard to go back to 2.x…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `input()` to read data, use `sys.stdin` instead:

```
for line is sys.stdin:
    poetry.append(line.lower().split())
```

This will read lines from the `stdin` file handle until closed, without throwing EOF exceptions. The loop body won't execute at all if `stdin` starts closed.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm more inclined to use input(), as that is what is expected of me for this task.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the differences between the two. `input` will strip each trailing newline (which doesn't matter, since you explicitly call `strip`). `input` will work better with certain IDEs/GUI wrappers (which doesn't matter unless you're using one). `input` will always run immediately, rather than possibly waiting until you hit the EOF, or at least fill a buffer (which doesn't matter since you're not running code that's nearly a slow as a `read` from a file or a human user, or timing-sensitive). Iterating the file is a lot simpler and easier to read (which always matters).

Answer (score 2):

Using `sys.stdin` as suggested by Martijn Pieters is the way to go here, but for completeness here is how you could continue to use `input()`.  You just need to catch the `EOFError` exception and exit the loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        poetry.append(input().lower().split())
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: You could make this into a simple `for` loop by using the two-argument form of [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter). (That doesn't mean you _should_. Especially since, to really do it nicely, you'd want to `iter` over a wrapper function that converts `EOFError` to returning a sentinel, at which point you might as well just write a wrapper generator instead.)